# Wifi driver not ready

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, drivers, realtek

I am facing issues with Realtek Wi-Fi card (8852be) when dual-booting Kali Linux alongside Windows on your HP Pavilion 14 ec1000x laptop wifi automatically gets disabled or not able to connect so give me a proper solution for this.

Answer (score -1):

Check for system updates first and foremost.
You can try to:

- Install the rtl8821ce-dkms kernel module. This module provides support for the Realtek Wi-Fi card (8852be).
- Disable Secure Boot in Windows. Secure Boot can sometimes interfere with the installation of the rtl8821ce-dkms kernel module.
- Boot Kali Linux in Safe Mode. This will disable all non-essential drivers, including the Wi-Fi driver. You can then install the rtl8821ce-dkms kernel module and reboot Kali Linux.